# How do I save changes made to data within a Userform back to the same row where the data came from?

Tags: excel, vba

I have found code to search a table and load cell values into the form.  I need to be able to make changes and save the form data back to the table to update the row.

This modified code works great to open the form, find the record and load the data.

```
' Written by Philip Treacy
' https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/searching-for-data-with-user-form
'

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim RecordRow As Long
    Dim RecordRange As Range

    ' Turn off default error handling so Excel does not display
    ' an error if the record number is not found
    On Error Resume Next
        
        ' Find the row in the table that the record is in
        RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBox1.Value), Range("JobSheet[W/O]"), 0)
        
        ' Set RecordRange to the first cell in the found record
        Set RecordRange = Range("JobSheet").Cells(1, 1).Offset(RecordRow - 1, 0)

        ' If an erro has occured i.e the record number was not found
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    
            ErrorLabel.Visible = True
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Sub
        
        End If
    
    ' Turn default error handling back on (Let Excel handle errors from now on)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If the code gets to here the record number was found
    ' Hide the error message 'Not Found'
    ErrorLabel.Visible = False
    ' and populate the form fields with the record's data
    TextBox4.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 6).Value
    TextBox5.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 5).Value
    TextBox2.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 15).Value
    TextBox3.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 16).Value
    CheckBoxBell.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 17).Value
    CheckBoxGas.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 18).Value
    CheckBoxHydro.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 19).Value
    CheckBoxWater.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 20).Value
    CheckBoxCable.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 21).Value
    CheckBoxOther1.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 22).Value
    CheckBoxOther2.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 23).Value
    CheckBoxOther3.Value = RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 24).Value
       
End Sub
```

I have been searching and for code to reinsert the data back into the row but have not been able to find a solution.

This is the User form:

[image: User Form]

I want to click the update button and have the data saved into the same row.  I know it is recommended to post code you have tried but I have tried so many things that there is no way I could post it and have it make any sense.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to find the answer before posting the question as well as trying to write a good question, so I don't think a downvote is fair.  If I can improve it somehow, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @cybernetic.nomad, I was able to create another sub that recorded the changes.  In case someone ends up here, I wanted to post the code for the solution.

```
Private Sub UpdateRecord()

     Dim RecordRow As Long
     Dim RecordRange As Range
        
        ' Find the row in the table that the record is in
        RecordRow = Application.Match(CLng(TextBoxWO.Value), Range("JobSheet[W/O]"), 0)
        
        ' Set RecordRange to the first cell in the found record
        Set RecordRange = Range("JobSheet").Cells(1, 1).Offset(RecordRow - 1, 0)

        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 5).Value = TextBoxComp.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBoxHold.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 8).Value = TextBoxDays.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 10).Value = CheckBoxLocate.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 15).Value = TextBoxFirst.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 16).Value = TextBoxOveride.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 17).Value = CheckBoxBell.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 18).Value = CheckBoxGas.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 19).Value = CheckBoxHydro.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 20).Value = CheckBoxWater.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 21).Value = CheckBoxCable.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 22).Value = CheckBoxOther1.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 23).Value = CheckBoxOther2.Value
        RecordRange(1, 1).Offset(0, 24).Value = CheckBoxOther3.Value
              
End Sub
```

It works perfectly!